# how to center a smaller Android view over another view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view that draws a graphic.  What I want to do is have the view be initially displayed as half its size (state a), then upon an event such as a button click, I want the view to expand to twice its size (state b).  There are a couple of problems I'm encountering here:

1) The first is positioning the view in state a such that its centered horizontally and vertically in relation to state b. pw_future is aligned on the top of the screen and as wide as the screen.  How do I get pw_spinner to be centered over this view?

2)  Right now, I'm specifying the width/height of pw_spinner in the XML file.  I don't like this because the screen size may be different depending on the hardware.  I really want it to be 1/2 the size of pw_future.  How can I do this?

I'm using a RelativeLayout (and not sure its the best option).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout" >

<com.todddavis.components.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/pw_future"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ProgressWheel:barColor="#FCEC5A"
    ProgressWheel:barLength="60dp"
    ProgressWheel:barWidth="10dp"
    ProgressWheel:delayMillis="75"
    ProgressWheel:rimColor="#343434"
    ProgressWheel:rimWidth="10dp"
    ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="30dp"
    ProgressWheel:text="state b"
    ProgressWheel:textColor="#FCEC5A"
    ProgressWheel:textSize="60sp" 
    />

<com.todddavis.components.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/pw_spinner"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    ProgressWheel:barColor="#FCEC5A"
    ProgressWheel:barLength="60dp"
    ProgressWheel:barWidth="5dp"
    ProgressWheel:delayMillis="75"
    ProgressWheel:rimColor="#343434"
    ProgressWheel:rimWidth="5dp"
    ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="30dp"
    ProgressWheel:textColor="#FCEC5A"
    ProgressWheel:textSize="60sp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align the views, you just use the exact same layout parameters for both.  Looks like you're using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for pw_spinner, remove that.  Also, add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to pw_spinner.

Comment: Yes, pw_spinner should have android:layout_alignParentTop="true", not android:layout_centerVertical="true".  The problem with this is pw_spinner is smaller than pw_future, and as such is not centered vertically over pw_future.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, so it shouldn't be aligned to the top of the parent.  In that case, I would suggest putting both Views inside their own RelativeLayout (I can't tell if that's what you've done, the layout is incomplete).  Once you've done that, then setting centerHorizontal and centerVertical on both views will work.